# LLVM: How to get up and running and use files in include/llvm/?

Tags: windows, compilation, llvm

I've downloaded the binary for Windows (here: http://llvm.org/builds/), but this doesn't include any of the files, e.g., "llvm/IRReader/IRReader.h", that many tutorials use.

Now, I've downloaded the LLVM source (here: http://releases.llvm.org/download.html), but instructing Visual Studio to look up include files in "include/llvm" results in lots of errors: header files cannot be opened, because they have a `cmake` suffix.

How do I get up and running fast without too much configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run CMake before you can do anything. That will create Visual Studio solution files, which you can then use the build the LLVM binary files from sources.  Only after you have build the binary files, you will be able to develop further applications linking to LLVM.

There is a platform independent guide here, also there used to be a windows specific guide too, which I could look for later.

http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html

For a first-time user of CMake I would recommend CMake-GUI, as it is much less of a hassle to use.

I think for starters one can use default settings. Just make sure to select the correct Version of Visual Studio, otherwise you might end up with incompatible solution files